# YII 2 joinWith жадная или ленивая загрузка

Tags: php, yii2

Метод joinWith иммет какую загрузку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызов метода joinWith() будет жадно загружать связные данные по умолчанию. Если вы не хотите получать связные данные, вы можете передать во втором параметре $eagerLoading значение false.